# Presumed incoherence in Python's struct.pack method

Tags: python, binary, pack

I am very confused right now.

If I pack a 7-length binary string, the result is the following:

```
>>> struct.pack('7s',b'\x1fBLOCK\n')
b'\x1fBLOCK\n'
```

Moreover, if I pack an unsigned long long, the result is:

```
>>> struct.pack('1Q',126208)
b'\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

But, if I pack both together, the reuslt adds an extra byte:

```
>>> struct.pack('7s1Q',b'\x1fBLOCK\n',126208)
b'\x1fBLOCK\n\x00\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Anyone knows why this extra byte appears?

> b'\x1fBLOCK\n **\x00**\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

This fact is ruining the binary reading of a custom file...

Answer (score 2):

The layout of bytes produced by `struct.pack` will (by default) match that produced by your platforms C compiler, which may include pad bytes between fields. You can disable this behaviour by adding a `=` to the start of your format string:

```
> struct.pack('7s1Q',b'\x1fBLOCK\n',126208) # C-style layout with padding bytes
'\x1fBLOCK\n\x00\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> struct.pack('=7s1Q',b'\x1fBLOCK\n',126208) # No padding
'\x1fBLOCK\n\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have used the `@` flag, which means that the byte order is the native one, and the final size is thus variable.

The solution lies on using a fixed size flag, such as `<`, `>`, `!` or `=`:

```
>>> struct.pack('<7s1Q',b'\x1fBLOCK\n',126208)
b'\x1fBLOCK\n\x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

The additional `\x00` is the string termination byte - in C a string is ended by  `\x00`.

You concattenate a string to a unsigned long long, so

> Note By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved

[applies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

```
b'\x1fBLOCK\n\x00   \x00\xed\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'  
    1 23456 7  8th   1   2   3   4   5   6    7   8
```